# How to autofill a string according to a last occurrence

Tags: r, string, cycle, autofill

I have this type of data set

```
10 .AAA
   .AAA
11 .BBB
   .BBB
20 .AAA
   .AAA
```

And I would like to get this:

```
10 .AAA
10 .AAA
11 .BBB
11 .BBB
20 .AAA
20 .AAA
```

I would like add a chunk of string from up row until another chunk appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can replace the blanks to `NA` and use `fill` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(col1 = na_if(col1, "")) %>%
   fill(col1)
```